# Can I use teamfoundation server from another domain?

Tags: tfs

I have a prod domain and a test domain, unfortunately in the only part I can install TFS ins a virtual machine in the test domain.

The question is, as developers, can we still access the tfs for source control? As far as I know it will use the windows credentials when connecting and those credentials wont exist in the test environment.

What can you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Team Explorer clients will try to authenticate with the default Windows credentials to the TFS server.  If you're on different domains (and there's no trust relationship between them) then this authentication will fail and you'll be prompted to enter your username/password for the TFS server.

If you don't wish to be prompted each time, you can set up credentials for the server in the Windows Credential Manager in your Control Panel.